# Add a category based on a range of column values in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame:

```
 df =
        id mu 
        1 -5
        2 -3
        3 0
        4 3
        5 25
```

How Can I set another column 'rating' based on a specific range of values of column 'mu':

`df['rating'] = 'A' if -1 >= mu <=1`

`df['rating'] = 'B' if -2 >= mu <=2`

`df['rating'] = 'C' if -3 >= mu <=3`

`df['rating'] = 'D' if -4 >= mu <=4`

`df['rating'] = 'F' if -5 < mu > 5`

Comment: Check `pd.cut()`. It does exactly what you need.

Comment: Where is `2` placed, as it satisfies conditions for both `A` and `B`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using pd.cut().

Changed to absolute values.

```
 df['abs_mu'] = df.mu.abs()

df=

      id  mu  abs_mu
    0   1  -5       5
    1   2  -3       3
    2   3   0       0
    3   4   2       2
    4   5  25      25
```

and then pd.cut()

```
pd.cut(df.abs_mu,[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, np.inf],labels=['A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], include_lowest=True)
```

Yields:

```
0    E
1    C
2    A
3    B
4    F
Name: abs_mu, dtype: category
Categories (6, object): [A < B < C < D < E < F]
```

Sorry, I feel stupid. 
Thanks for your time.